# HTML play wav from ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, audio

I'm trying to play a wav file returned from a REST API call.

I have tried prefacing the source with "data:audio/wav;base64"
I have also tried using different combinations of btoa, URL.createObjectURL and other suggestions online but none of them seem to work.

If I enter the URL in the browser directly, it works.
If I do a console.out on the response, it looks like:
RIFF����WAVEfmt with lots more of those ? icons afterwards

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?accept=audio%2Fwav&voice=en-US_AllisonVoice&text="Hello World",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
    },
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        $("#wav_src").attr("src", data);
        $("#speech").trigger("load");
        alert("done");
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<audio controls id="speech" preload="none">
    <source id="wav_src" type="audio/wav">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </source>
</audio>
```

Comment: can you try like : `$('#wav_src').get(0).play();` instead of `$("#speech").trigger("load");`. Before that `console.log(data)` and see if you are getting correct url. otherwise fix it first.

Comment: console.log(data) gives me:RIFF����WAVEfmt with lots more of those ? icons... $('#wav_src').get(0).play() = Uncaught TypeError: $(...).get(...).play is not a function